# stuck on changing each row color during run-time in listview in asp.net based on database entries

Tags: asp.net, listview

I want to change color of each row in a listview based on a data which is stored in database.
I've written following code but I don't know by the help of which object I can access to markup property of listview :

```
 protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
        {
            ListViewDataItem dataitem = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;
            int policyid = (int)DataBinder.Eval(dataitem.DataItem, "policyID");
            if(policyid == 3)
            //what should I write here to change the corresponding row's color?

        }


    }
```

regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey Austin Powers here is the code

**ASPX CODE :**

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1"   runat="server" 
            onitemdatabound="ListView1_ItemDataBound">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            EmpID
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            EmpName
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Department
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Age
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Address
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder">
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr id="MainTableRow" runat="server">
                    <td id="EmpID" runat="server">
                        <asp:Label ID="EmpIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EmpID") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td id="EmpNameTD" runat="server">
                        <asp:Label ID="EmpNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EmpName") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td id="DepartmentTD" runat="server">
                        <asp:Label ID="DepartmentLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Department") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td id="AgeTD" runat="server">
                        <asp:Label ID="AgeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Age") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td id="AddressTD" runat="server">
                        <asp:Label ID="AddressLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Address") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
```

**AND HERE IS THE CODEBEHIND CODE**

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var Employee = new { EmpID = 1, EmpName = "Rahul Jain", Department = "IT", Age = 33, Address = "Hello" };
        var customerList = (new[] { Employee }).ToList();

        customerList.Add(new { EmpID = 2, EmpName = "Rahul Jain", Department = "IT", Age = 33, Address = "Hello" });
        customerList.Add(new { EmpID = 3, EmpName = "Rahul Jain", Department = "IT", Age = 33, Address = "Hello" });
        customerList.Add(new { EmpID = 4, EmpName = "Rahul Jain", Department = "IT", Age = 33, Address = "Hello" });
        customerList.Add(new { EmpID = 5, EmpName = "Rahul Jain", Department = "IT", Age = 33, Address = "Hello" });
        customerList.Add(new { EmpID = 6, EmpName = "Rahul Jain", Department = "IT", Age = 33, Address = "Hello" });

        customerList.Add(new { EmpID = 7, EmpName = "Rahul Jain", Department = "IT", Age = 33, Address = "Hello" });
        customerList.Add(new { EmpID = 8, EmpName = "Rahul Jain", Department = "IT", Age = 33, Address = "Hello" });
        customerList.Add(new { EmpID = 9, EmpName = "Rahul Jain", Department = "IT", Age = 33, Address = "Hello" });
        customerList.Add(new { EmpID = 10, EmpName = "Rahul Jain", Department = "IT", Age = 33, Address = "Hello" });


        ListView1.DataSource = customerList;
        ListView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
        {
            ListViewDataItem dataitem = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;
            int policyid = (int)DataBinder.Eval(dataitem.DataItem, "EmpID");
            if (policyid == 3)
            {
                HtmlTableRow cell = (HtmlTableRow)e.Item.FindControl("MainTableRow");

                cell.BgColor = "Red";
            }
        }
    }
```

tHANKS